# How to use a python IDE as a substitute for command prompt?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It is possible to open a program on your pc using the command prompt. Is there a way to use a Python IDE or an idea for code that helps me do that?

Comment: It depends on what (you think what) "open" means.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
import os
os.startfile("application_name.exe")
```

Or if you want to run external applications too, you need to check the path for this application.

```
import os
os.chdir(r'C:\program files\programfolder')
os.startfile("application_name.exe")
```